# Cant find table-rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying find and  `Delete` the rows `<tr>` as you see in code below, but for some reason it can't find elements.

```js
$('#ResultProduct').on('click', '.deletebtn', function(e) {
  var targetElement = $(e.target);

  $(targetElement).closest("tr").find('.RMAJS').remove();
  $(targetElement).closest("tr").find('.section').remove();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="ResultProduct">
    <tr>
      <td><a class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="RMAJS">
      <td>some text 1</td>
      <td>some text 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section">
      <td>some text 1</td>
      <td>some text 1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><a class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="RMAJS">
      <td>some text 2</td>
      <td>some text 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="section">
      <td>some text 2</td>
      <td>some text 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone please help me!

Comment: `$(targetElement).closest("tr")` refers the row the button is placed, that row doesn't contain the element with the selected class.

Comment: I suggest having a `tbody` for each group of rows you want to delete. Then you can just use `$(targetElement).closest("tbody").remove()` and be on your merry way...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The element `tbody` can exists only one time, but if exists you have to reference it.

Comment: @reporter Please reference a standard that says `tbody` may exist only one time. [The `HTMLTableElement` has a `tBodies` (plural) property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/tBodies) because you can have more than one.

Comment: @reporter: “*You may use more than one <tbody> per table as long as they are all consecutive. This lets you divide the rows in large tables into sections...*” (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

Comment: Ok. Didn't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `closest()` then `find()` will go up to the `tr` then back down into the element using `find()`. You would need to `find('tbody')` then look inside that element to `find('.RMAJS')`.

This wouldn't solve your issue, because you would end up removing all `.RMAJS` elements from the `tbody` when it looks like all you want to do is remove the next elements.

In your case, you're going to want to use `next()` rather than `find()`.

```js
$('#ResultProduct').on('click', '.deletebtn', function(e) {
  var targetElement = $(e.target);

  $(targetElement).closest("tr").next('.RMAJS').remove();
  $(targetElement).closest("tr").next('.section').remove();

})
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id="ResultProduct">
        <tr>
            <td><a class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="RMAJS">
            <td>some text 1</td>
            <td>some text 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section">
            <td>some text 1</td>
            <td>some text 1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a class="deletebtn">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="RMAJS">
            <td>some text 2</td>
            <td>some text 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section">
            <td>some text 2</td>
            <td>some text 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help and Thanks for explanation :) its workin but when rows get deleted  i end it with 2 delete buttons in screen , can i use  closest and next to remove delete button too or closest and find ?!

Comment: sure, you could add: `$(targetElement).closest("tr").remove()` as well and it should remove the delete row.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function removeRow(row) {
    $(row).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script><table>
    <tbody id="ResultProduct">
        <tr>
           
        </tr>
        <tr class="RMAJS">
            <td>some text 1</td>
            <td>some text 1</td>
           <td><a  onclick="removeRow(this)" class="deletebtn" href="#">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="section">
            <td>some text 1</td>
            <td>some text 1</td>
                     <td><a  onclick="removeRow(this)" class="deletebtn" href="#">Delete</a></td>

        </tr>

      
        <tr class="RMAJS">
            <td>some text 2</td>
            <td>some text 2</td>
                     <td><a  onclick="removeRow(this)" class="deletebtn" href="#">Delete</a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="section">
            <td>some text 2</td>
            <td>some text 2</td>
                     <td><a  onclick="removeRow(this)" class="deletebtn" href="#">Delete</a></td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```